# mkfifo to copy / move files

Tags: files, archive, mkfifo

Is it possible to use mkfifo (named pipes) in Linux to copy files?

For example: I am extracting files from tar archive and I want them to be moved immediately to another location.

Comment: you can use `tar -C` to specify a location. unclear how you want fifo to come into play here.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `mkfifo` to copy or move files, no. `mkfifo` creates a named pipe. You can use a pipe to arrange for data to go to a different place, and occasionally a named pipe is the only way or is more convenient. [You can find some solutions that use `mkfifo` on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=mkfifo+is%3Aa). But a pipe isn't usually useful if you *only* want data to end up in a different place: for that, redirection is enough.

If you want to extract files from a tar archive and put them in a different place than the path inside the archive, named pipes aren't going to help you at all. Instead, use the `--transform` option of GNU tar or the `-s` option of BSD tar or pax to rewrite the file paths during the extraction.